# How to allow IIS to access path variable?

Tags: batch-file, iis, iis-7, cgi, fastcgi

I have the following php code which I deploy it in iis8 server.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p>Hello word !!!!!!!</p>
<a href="<?php exec('file.bat');?>"> click me</a>
</body>
</html>
```

the file.bat is as follow.

```
@echo off{
java 1>>logfile.txt 2>>errorfile.txt
}
```

When I run  the I run the application I get the following error in errorfile.txt

```
java exe n est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne
```

But when I modify file.bat to

```
 @echo off{
    C:\java\jdk\bin\java 1>>logfile.txt 2>>errorfile.txt 
    }
```

It works well and the logfile contain the "java help".

In the other side if I double click the first file(file.bat) also work which means that the path variable are well edited.

Any explanation why IIS can't use the path environment variable to get commands locations and how to fix this issue?

Comment: What is the path for the IIS user.

Comment: I means instead I add java, android , ant in the environment variable PATH and I run my application web I get the following error in the logfile.
java not recognized as internal or external command